# How was Israel's livestock fed in the desert?

Tags: food, animals, shemot-exodus

The Children of Israel were fed the Manna for 40 years. But how were the numerous heads of cattle which accompanied them out of Egypt fed?

What information is available in the Torah and the Midrash?